# Unit test for server polling using RxJava, Kotlin

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, rx-java2

I'm trying to create a test using JUnit and Mockito for the following scenario: make a call to the server, in case the response is not successful, retry the request.

```
repository.uploadModel(model)
                .subscribeOn(schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(schedulers.ui())
                .repeatWhen (repeatTimer)
                .subscribe({
                    if (it.isSuccessful) {
                        mvpView?.showUploadComplete()
                    } else {
                        mvpView?.showGeneralUploadError()
                    }
                }, {
                     it.printStackTrace()
                })
```

So far I came up with this:

```
val model = Mockito.mock(Model::class.java)
val errorResponse = Response.error<Any>(500, ResponseBody.create(null, ""))

whenever(repository.uploadModel(model))           
    .thenReturn(Flowable.just(errorResponse))

presenter?.uploadModel()
testScheduler?.triggerActions()

verify(view, atLeast(5)).pendingUpload()
```

**What actually happens**: `showGeneralUploadError()` is called only once and then the test ends and fails.
**What I want to happen**: call `showGeneralUploadError()` multiple times

Extra info:

1. `repeatTimer` is defined as `{ it: Flowable<Any> -> it.delay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}` for unit testing
2. `repeatTimer` is defined as `{ it: Flowable<Any> -> it.delay(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}` for production
3. This is only sample code to demonstrate the problem, not actual code

Comment: Try using `retry` or `retryWhen` functors in the Observable class. You can configure it to retry an operation x times if the operation fails. `retryWhen` is like `retry` except your provide a predicate which is evaluated to determine if the retry should be carried out or skipped.

Comment: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

Comment: Also, I doubt you want to "retry the request until it's complete" you probably want an upper bound on the amount of attempts before displaying something to the user such as "server is down, retry later".

Comment: With regards to testing it with Mockito, read this (search the page for "retry" - it covers exactly what you need): https://medium.com/@fabioCollini/testing-asynchronous-rxjava-code-using-mockito-8ad831a16877

Comment: @ThomasCook indeed, there was no bound. I only wanted to show the idea so I removed unneeded code. I read the both articles, but the retryWhen didn't really fit with what I wanted to accomplish, but it was a really good suggestion and read!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was at `repeatTimer`. I tried to declare it for mocking purposes as:

`repeatTimer is defined as { it: Flowable<Any> -> it.delay(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS)}`

but it should have been just

`{ it: Flowable<Any> -> it}`

Answer (score 2):

The `takeUntil()` operator would only respond to data emitted via `onNext()`. Since your test never emits a data value, there is nothing for it to do.

It's not clear from your sample code what you are trying to accomplish, so I can't suggest what you can do to fix this.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and pointing that out. Removed the `takeUntil` as it didn't add any value to my question. In the meantime I found a solution. If you think I could have done it in a better way, please point it out.